# Jsoup vs groovy XmlSlurper?

Tags: groovy, jsoup, xmlslurper

I am looking at parsing some xml content for my application (based on groovy) and I am stuck at this point where I have to choose between JSoup and groovy's native XMLSlurper.

RSS Feeds parsed are of medium size not exceeding more than 25 items. So the size of the content being parsed is neither too much nor too less.

Although the content is of medium size, parsing of content happens several times. So in terms of overhead and speed, which of the two is a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parsing 25 items, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

I'd use `XmlSlurper` first, as it doesn't add a dependency to your project and is integrated tightly into Groovy, but then consider other options if for some reason it does not work as well as expected

Answer (score 1):

XmlSlurper. TagSoup is really for the vagaries of HTML.

Pretty easy to do a speed comparison though, no?

Comment: Speed comparison? Are you suggesting me to use a profiler or something of the sort?

Comment: @VeeKay wrapping the parsing with prints of currentTimeMillis would probably be sufficient.